# Replace all occurances of JSON keys having - to _ character

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json from Google pagespeed api, which needs to be exported to big query. Since BQ doesnt support the keys having - symbol, I must replace all the key names those have - char to _

Please note that I cannot perform a find and replace on entire string as the values need a - char. The json structure can be complex and I understand the only ways to do is by iterating all the keys of nested objects.

I found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

but could not iterate the nested json, as I cannot predetermine the json structure and all that must be dynamically decided
Any pointers how to replace all chars would be great

```
[{
    "id-person": "5078c3a803-ff4197dc81fbfb",
    "email-name": "user1@gmail.com",
    "image": "some_image_url",
    "name-page": {
        "id-person": "5078c3a803ff-4197dc81fbfb",
        "email-name": {
            "id-person": "5078c3a803ff41-97dc81fbfb",
            "email-name": "user1@gmail.com",
            "image": [{
                "id-person": "5078c3a803ff4197dc-81fbfb",
                "email-name": "user1@gmail.com",
                "image": "some_image_url",
                "name-page": "Name 1"
            }, {
                "id-person": "5078c3a8-03ff4197dc81fbfb",
                "email-name": "user1-12@gmail.com",
                "image": "some_image_url",
                "name-page": "Name 1"
            }]
            "name-page": "Name 1"
        }
        "image": "some_image_url",
        "name-page": "Name 1"
    }
}]
```

Comment: _"javascript object rename properties"_ + _"javascript object iterate deep"_ + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 3):

A recursive method such as this will do it. You need to check each value for an array or an object and continue the recursion.

```
const replaceKeys = obj => {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map( ([key,value]) => {
      return [
        key.replace("-","_"),
        Array.isArray(value)
          ? value.map(replaceKeys)
          :typeof value == "object"
            ? replaceKeys(value)
            : value
      ];
    }))
}
```

Live example:

```js
const input = [{
    "id-person": "5078c3a803-ff4197dc81fbfb",
    "email-name": "user1@gmail.com",
    "image": "some_image_url",
    "name-page": {
        "id-person": "5078c3a803ff-4197dc81fbfb",
        "email-name": {
            "id-person": "5078c3a803ff41-97dc81fbfb",
            "email-name": "user1@gmail.com",
            "image": [{
                "id-person": "5078c3a803ff4197dc-81fbfb",
                "email-name": "user1@gmail.com",
                "image": "some_image_url",
                "name-page": "Name 1"
            }, {
                "id-person": "5078c3a8-03ff4197dc81fbfb",
                "email-name": "user1-12@gmail.com",
                "image": "some_image_url",
                "name-page": "Name 1"
            }],
            "name-page": "Name 1"
        },
        "image": "some_image_url",
        "name-page": "Name 1"
    }
}]

const replaceKeys = obj => {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map( ([key,value]) => {
      return [
        key.replace("-","_"),
        Array.isArray(value)
          ? value.map(replaceKeys)
          :typeof value == "object"
            ? replaceKeys(value)
            : value
      ];
    }))
}


const result = input.map(replaceKeys);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I tested this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lFYW26xsPGQp6WU9h6f2-E1bHW-hDIic/view?usp=sharing JSON and it *gives me the error*  Cannot convert undefined or null to object. Could you help me please

Comment: Sorry @CodeGuy I cant get to that address.